# Rails nested association and restarted numbering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a nested resource like so:

```
resources :users
  resources :posts
end
```

and a `user` `has_many` `posts`, it is possible to have Rails start numbering based on the parent association in the URL? For example, currently, nesting resources just grabs the ID:

```
@user.posts.find(params[:id])
```

This correctly namespaces the posts, only allowing posts from `@user`... however, is there a way such that the `post_id` is independent? I.E. I want each user's posts to start at 1, where:

```
/users/1/posts/1
/users/2/posts/1
```

Actually refer to two different posts?

Comment: The `id` is shared since all of the User objects are sharing a single `posts` table.  Each user would need a separate table to individualize each "Post" or drop using :id and make it some other attribute that's manually incremented by the model based on the User association.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be quite a bit of work, but basically you can do it with these steps:

1. Create a migration to add a new attribute to store the specific user-post count. (I used `user_post_id`)
2. Override `Post`'s `to_param` method to use the new value you just created. (It has to be a string.)

   - `to_param` is the method that the `url` and `path` helpers use.
3. Create a `before_save` filter that will actually increment the `user_post_id` value for each new post.
4. Change all your controller methods to find on `user_post_id`

   ```
   @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
   @post = @user.posts.where(:user_post_id => (params[:id])).first
   ```
5. Change all your Views that might not work now

You can see the source here: [Custom Nested Resource URL example](https://github.com/Azolo/Custom-Nested-Resource-URL-example)

### Code

migration:

```
class AddUserPostIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :user_post_id, :integer
  end
end
```

post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_next_user_post_id
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_post_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :user_id}

  def to_param
    self.user_post_id.to_s
  end

private
  def set_next_user_post_id
    self.user_post_id ||= get_new_user_post_id
  end

  def get_new_user_post_id
    user = self.user
    max = user.posts.maximum('user_post_id') || 0
    max + 1
  end
end
```

A couple controller methods
posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml

  before_filter :find_user

  def index
    @posts = @user.posts.all
    respond_with @posts
  end

  def show
    @post = @user.posts.where(:user_post_id => (params[:id])).first
    respond_with [@user, @post]
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have the Users Model assign the index to Posts? That way the Posts Model doesn't need to reach up into the Users Model.

Comment: I don't think so. The `User` model would be reaching into the `posts` collection every time instead. I think that you wouldn't be decreasing complexity by changing it, instead the complexity would just be moved. Since `User` doesn't need this particular knowledge of how the `Post` model is coupled, I put it in the `Post` model.