# Incrementing an index on a has_many dependent resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uniqueidentifier, has-many

I have an project with many Books. Each book has many Pages. I would like each page to have a pageIndex that makes it unique in relation to the book, so that each time I build a page through the book this index is incremented. Obviously all models have their own id, but that id is unique across all Pages. I would like the first Page built by a Book to have a a pageIndex of 0, the second to have a pageIndex of 1, the third; 2 etc.

I could do something like this:

```
book = User.books.last
pageIndex = book.pages.count
book.pages.create(:pageIndex => pageIndex)
```

But it seems to me that it would be much nicer if this index was set automatically by the book when it created a dependant resource of type Page. Is there a way of doing this?

Please note that I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752120/rails-nested-association-and-restarted-numbering) but what I am looking for is a hook in the parent/owning Resource that allows me to do something to the dependant resource it has created after it has created it and before it saves it. Something like the before_save callback but related to creation of a dependent resource: after_dependent_create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associations also have some callbacks. See here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html "Association callbacks". Possible callbacks are: before_add, after_add, before_remove and after_remove.

Also I would add a counter_cache on the book so you'll know how many pages you have and when creating a new page you won't have to count the existing pages

Comment: Thanks. Used before_add to increment the index.