# Increment by 1 with respect to User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a new rails developer who's trying to do the following

I have a post model that has a belongs_to User relationship.

Currently If you go to for example: `example.com/username/posts/3`, it shows the 3rd post in the **entire** posts table. I'm trying to have it so that I can have routes like `example.com/username/posts/3` and have it display the third post belonging to **that user**.

So what I'm trying to do is something like this: In the model have it save a number starting at 1, and incrementing, based on the user.

Here's my post model:

```
attr_accessible :description, :name, :content
belongs_to :users
```

and here's my users model (i'm using devise):

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username
```

Is this the best way to implement something like this? How I can implement something like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails nested association and restarted numbering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752120/rails-nested-association-and-restarted-numbering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show the post for the specific user you will need to use the current_user method in devise. For example in your controller you could call something like so

```
current_user.posts
```

that would list the posts for that current user. To stop others users from accessing another users post use cancan gem for authorization.