# Rails Type Mismatch Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8753998/561634 and trying to make a user_post_id based on the user just like described in the answer.

The end goal is to have urls like website.com/username/posts/4 where 4 is the 4th post from that specific user, instead of like now where website.com/username/posts/4 would show the 4th post in the database.

I'm getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in PostsController#create User(#2171866060) expected, got String(#2152189000)
```

my controller create method looks like this:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.user = current_user.id
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(username: current_user.username, id: @post.id), notice: 'Post was successfully created.'  }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

my model looks like this:

```
before_save :set_next_user_post_id

validates :user_post_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :user}

def to_param
  self.user_post_id.to_s
end
belongs_to :user

private
def set_next_user_post_id
  self.user_post_id ||= get_new_user_post_id
end

def get_new_user_post_id
  user = self.user
  max = user.posts.maximum('user_post_id') || 0
  max + 1
end
```

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
 @post.user = current_user.id
```

Should either be `@post.user = current_user` or `@post.user_id = current_user.id`

Comment: I actually have an integer field in my posts table called user. Sorry, should have mentioned that in the question

Comment: You have `belongs_to :user` in your model, which will assume `@post.user = ` will be getting an instance of `User`. Why do you have an integer field called `user`? It should probably be `user_id` if you want to follow rails conventions (you probably want to).

Comment: Having an association and a column with the same name is a really bad idea.